# HP Pavilion 600 - can I change fn and f keys behavior?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, hp, shortcuts

The default behavior of the  pavilion 600 keyboard forces you to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to use the fkeys, which is terrible. Is there any hope to change this behaviour or do I have no option but manually changing the shortcuts for every f and media key?

I'm using Ubuntu 18 with KDE, if that matters.

Comment: Does my answer helps you? If so, please tick it as *Accepted*; if not, can you explain what's wrong by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1182894/edit) your question, or by commenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> key behavior must be change directly inside the BIOS.

To access at BIOS, turn ON your computer and press immediately <kbd>F10</kbd> key (you can spam the key, but it's as effective if you stay pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> key until you see BIOS window) -> *I say <kbd>F10</kbd> key, but it could change in function of your computer*

Go to `System Configuration` -> `Action Key Mode`

Switch **off** / **Disabled** this option to have <kbd>F1</kbd> and others keys as primary (increase volume must be done with <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>)

Source : [HP documentation](https://support.hp.com/id-en/document/c02035108)

Comment: Thanks! the settings were slightly different for my Dell latitude.

Comment: I didn't write the answer for a Dell latitude, because you mentionned th HP Pavillon 600 in the question post, but nevermind, glad to see that it helps you :)

Comment: Yeah no problem man, I'll update this post later with my details.